# XSLT: multiple attributes and loop through attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML format like

```
<person>
<order column1="test1" column2="test2" column3="test1" column4="test2">
</person>
```

i need result like this
The column may increase dynamically i need result based on that 
column1=test1  
column2=test2 
column3=test1 
column4=test2

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-each to achieve  this output:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/person/order/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#x000a;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

See Mentioned link: http://xsltransform.net/asnmyc/1